# Prevent Model object from being created

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class CommonUser(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(User)
  field = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class SpecificUserA(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(CommonUser)
  field_a = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class SpecificUserB(models.Model):
  user = models.OneToOneField(CommonUser)
  field_b = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

This allows me to have have shared information between `SpecificUserA` and `SpecificUserB`.  This does not prevent me from creating both a `SpecificUserA` and `SpecificUserB` object for one `User` object:

```
u = User.objects.create_user(username='user1')
u.save()

u.commonuser = CommonUser(field="user1 field data")
u.commonuser.save()

u.commonuser.specificusera = SpecificUserA(field_a="user1 field_a data")
u.commonuser.specificusera.save()

# how can I prevent this?
u.commonuser.specificuserb = SpecificUserB(field_b="user1 field_b data")
u.commonuser.specificuserb.save()
```

I know I can put in conditions to check whether a `User` object with a specific user name exists before creating `Specific` objects, but is there a check that catches the above scenario?

Comment: Any reason your not using model inheritance here? Might not make much difference, but might inform a response.

Comment: I was following the example from the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).  From what I understand, [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) results in a one-to-one field being created for the derived model.